# Junction box on 1x2 running board?

Tags: electrical, junction-box

Is it kosher to put junction boxes directly on 1x2 running board, like this? [image: Junction box on running board]

It doesnt look right, being wider than the running board. Also looks like the running board should be further away so the wire doesn't have to bend as severely...

Elsewhere we have stuff like this that also looks weird, but at least the junction box looks secure: [image: junction box attached to floor joist]

This is all hidden behind a drop ceiling so it can look silly, if it's fine. It just didn't pass my novice smell test.

Comment: The mounting isn't the issue. Having junction boxes closed in a ceiling is the problem.

Comment: @RMDman, I thought that junction boxes above a *drop ceiling* was ok? Aren't standard fluorescent strip lights (for decades the most common drop ceiling fixture) basically a junction box?

Comment: I believe junction boxes above a drop ceiling are no problem at all, since they can be accessed without needing any tools.  It's only if they require tools or other unusual access methods that is not allowed.  Also, in my (non-professional opinion) those junction boxes look fine, and attached to a running board is perfectly acceptable, and that bend radius is no problem at all.

Comment: This could be an issue of regional terms.  In my area a "drop ceiling" Is one built to lower the existing ceiling, but is still a closed in ceiling. . A "suspended ceiling" has panels that can be easily removed.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I call it both, but maybe "Drop" is wrong. It's the type with panels that you can remove.

Thanks for everyone's help so far though, sounds like I shouldn't complain :)

Comment: Nope, around here, a drop ceiling has panels that *drop* into place, i.e. are not fastened.